# Is it possible to add Roles as foreign keys in the ApplicationUser class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show all the users with their roles. I am thinking of doing something like this in the ApplicationUser class:

```
 public string RoleId {get; set;}
 [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
 public UserManager Role {get; set;}
```

Of course this doesn't return the correct results, but I think there might be a workaround...

Comment: Having `UserManager` as the Role type definitely won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The default identity schema uses a `UserRoles` table to associate a user's roles to them. If you implemented a custom [IdentityDbContext<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-8?view=aspnetcore-2.0) you could create the foreign key relationship between your `ApplicationUser`, `UserRole` and `IdentityRole` implementations.

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set }

    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
    public IdentityRole Role { get; set }
}

IQueryable<ApplicationUser> GetUsers(IdentityDb db)
{
    return db.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role);
}
```